# Failure recovery strategy: aws load balancer down

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

what happens when a aws load balancer is down, this single point of failure may cause the whole system to be unavailable, what's the best strategy to recover in this case; how to prevent service to be unavailable.

Do we also need replication for Loadbalancer to prevent data loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application Load Balancer (ALB), Network Load Balancer (NLB) and Classic Load Balancer (CLB) are **managed services** offered by AWS. AWS guarantees their availability:

> Elastic Load Balancing **guarantees** a monthly availability of at least **99.99%** for your load balancers (Classic, Application or Network). To learn more about the SLA and know if you are qualified for a credit, visit https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/sla/.

To further ensure high availability of your ALB, you **must** use it over at least 2 availability zones (AZs). For NLB and CLB you can also use it **across multiple** AZs.

You can also further read about their reliability in AWS **whitepaper**:

- [Reliability Pillar AWS Well-Architected Framework](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS-Reliability-Pillar.pdf)

Thus returning to your question:

> Do we also need replication for Loadbalancer to prevent data loss?

You don't have to. Its **AWS responsibility** to manage and ensure that their load balances work and AWS guarantees that. Instead its better to focus on your instances and ensure that they are highly available and fault tolerant.